# Passing a binary file from Python3 to Python2 on Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

We have two python scripts, which need to communicate over stdin/out (on Windows). Sadly they both have to be in different Python versions. The snippets are:

**Source (Python 3):**

```
sys.stderr.write("LEN1: %s\n" % len(source_file.read()))
subprocess.check_call(["C:\\python2.exe", "-u", "-c",
"""
import foo
foo.to_json()
"""], stdin=source_file, stdout=json_file, stderr=sys.stderr, env=os.environ)
```

**Target (Python 2):**

```
def to_json():
  import msvcrt
  msvcrt.setmode(sys.stdin.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)
  input_message = sys.stdin.read()
  sys.stderr.write("LEN2: %s\n" % len(input_message))
```

When I execute the scripts, I get:

```
LEN2: 0
LEN1: 37165
```

It seems like I am doing something fundamentally wrong, but cannot really figure out, what exactly. Could anyone try to help me debug, where I am going wrong.

Comment: Have you tried using a `Popen` with pipes and talking to it with `communicate`? https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen

Comment: The `setmode` call in `to_json` is redundant since the `-u` argument sets `stdin` to binary mode. Passing `env=os.environ` is probably redundant, unless `os.environ` has somehow gotten out of sync with the process environment.

Answer (score 3):

After the first `source_file.read()` to determine the file's length, the file pointer is at the end of the file. By the time you've passed the stream to `check_call()`, you've exhausted it, and further reads will produce the empty string. This can be worked around in two ways:

A. Read the file into memory before calculating its length.

B. Before `check_call()`, rewind the file object to the beginning of the file with `source_file.seek(0)`.

Comment: Thanks. Then seems like all data is received fine.